# Efficient Graph data structure that supports very fast node and edge deletion in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I am looking for a graph that supports very fast edge and node deletion. I am currently using an adjacency list like this

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> _graph_adj;` which where the inner vector represents the nodes of the various outgoing arcs from a node in outer vector.

But if I need to delete a particular arc, say (5, 10), I have to search for 10 in the vector `_graph_adj[5]` and then remove it, which seems very computationally inefficient. And similarly for node deletion, it is very expensive as I have to find out where that node occurs in the adjacency lists.   Is there a way to have a good data structure that supports very fast edge and node deletion.

For what it's worth, my matrices are very small, like 50 nodes and 200 edges maximum. I am also using this data structure to perform Dijkstra on it. As in remove some nodes and then do Dijkstra.

Comment: If you can sacrifice a little bit of memory, consider using `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: use an adjacency matrix. your graph is small enough you should not need to use a bit array or anything like that.

Comment: @Rob thanks. I can "delete" the nodes and arcs by simply setting the incident arcs and the deleted arc values to a very large value, which, for Dijkstra is equivalent of deleting the edges.